# Code stuck while calling getResourceasStream() under Java web Start

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

My code is running fine in eclipse, but when I am trying to run the same code using Java web start, it automatically terminated and not able to call `getResourceAsStream()` method.

Here is the code

```
   public ImageIcon loadImageIcon ( String name ) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {

      logger.info("entering resource loader class in loadimage icond method");
      logger.info("object is "+this);
      logger.info("class is "+this.getClass());
      logger.info("class loader is "+this.getClass().getClassLoader()+" object trying to load is "+name);
      InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream( name ) ;
      logger.debug("loadimageicon:  loading image inside resource loader "+this.getClass().getResource(name).getPath());
      ImageIcon   returnImage = null ;
     if ( in != null ) {
         returnImage = new ImageIcon ( InputStreamLoader.load ( in ) ) ;
         in.close() ;
      } else
         throw new FileNotFoundException ( name ) ;
      return( returnImage ) ;
   }
```

and here are the logs

```
[2012-10-03 13:15:03,015] [Thread-21] INFO  com.test.nzna.shared.util.ResourceLoader  - object is com.ibm.nzna.shared.util.ResourceLoader@1b7f958
[2012-10-03 13:15:03,015] [Thread-21] INFO  com.test.nzna.shared.util.ResourceLoader  - class is class com.ibm.nzna.shared.util.ResourceLoader
[2012-10-03 13:15:03,015] [Thread-21] INFO  com.test.nzna.shared.util.ResourceLoader  - class loader is com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader@1bf68a9 object trying to load is Default\logon.gif
```

I repeat the code is running perfectly fine in eclipse.

Comment: Any errors/exceptions? Can you check if the resource you are asking for is in the war file you are deploying?

Comment: that is the problem, that there is no exception or error, otherwise I would try to debug that :(

Comment: The title say "code gets stuck", but the question says that the application "terminates". If it's getting stuck, then that might be a socket problem (timeout issue?), but if the application (and VM?) is terminating, then that seems worse.  Can you use a remote debugger and dive into the code?

Comment: I am sorry, my bad. it is application terminates and also i do not know how to use remove debugger, if you provide me any link I can work with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I have found the answer of my problem, I was passing "`File.separator`" as a name of the image file which was causing it to not find the resource so I changed it to "`/`" and it started working again perfectly fine in eclipse and in java web start